# Ajax only pagination in ASP.NET MVC with PagedList.MVC or similar

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, pagination

I use troygoode's PagedList to output paginated links in my ASP.NET MVC application http://nuget.org/packages/PagedList.Mvc

I create the paged list inside my controller, and then pass it to the view, which uses @Html.PagedlistPager to generate the html for the paginated links. This generates a bunch of links like /Store?search=bla&page=1, /Store?search=bla&page=2 etc.

It is pretty well agreed upon that javascript code should be separated from html where possible, and so I add click handlers to all paginated links in a separate javascript file. And ofcourse inside these click handlers I perform an ajax request to get page X, which is rendered server side and then dumped into a div on the client page -- including new paginated links.

Since I am generating new paginated links for every request, I add these click handlers every time a new search is done or the page is changed. I do this from the ajax's OnSuccess event handler.

This works great. The user can navigate through pages even if they have javascript disabled, as it falls back to the regular href. Graceful degradation at it's finest.

However, there is a different part of my app where the user is required to select a Store when logging a job, and it's strictly ajax only. In this case, I want the href for the paginated links to be 'javascript:void(0);'. The problem is, when adding click handlers for these links, I now have no way of knowing which url the ajax call should be posting to.

I suppose I could just use the text value of the link - "1", "2", "3", etc.. but what about the "Next" and "Previous" links? Plus it feels wrong doing it this way.

Ideally, PagedList.MVC would have an option to put data-page="X" attributes in each of the page links and then I could use this in my click handlers, but the fact that such an option does not exist in such a popular .net extension leads me to believe that my proposed solution is not the ideal or preferred solution.

Is my approach logical? Or is there a better way of doing this. Do I need to write my own helper to use instead of PageList.MVC's standard helper? I just need some guidance from a person who has done this before and has confidence in their approach.

Thanks for reading

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the support for unobtrusive AJAX that I just pushed in:

https://github.com/TroyGoode/PagedList/issues/26#issuecomment-6471793

Comment: I ended up creating my own implementation, I think yours needs some serious work.